# Multi-line commands in the sails console

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Wrote multi-line command in the sails console but couldn't execute them. Tried ending with semicolon ':', pressing ctrl/alt/shift enter, but all they do is create new lines. 
How to execute multi-line commands in sails console?

Just a simple example:

```
User.find()
.where({“name”:”John”})
.update({
“name” : “JohnGalt”
});
```

Instead of all in the same line ..

Comment: Please post an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you move the period from the beginning to the end it should work.  For example:

```
User.find().
where({"name":"John"}).
exec(console.log);
```